# Long tag names cause the total question count to be truncated

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, google-chrome

For example, on [How to use an input field as query parameter to a destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6192517/113124)

[image: the google-chrome-extension tag causes an overflow]

```
Google Chrome   12.0.733.0 (Official Build 81210) unknown
WebKit  534.29 (trunk@83482)
V8  3.2.9
```

Comment: question was edited and long tag is gone :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/2869827/11343 is OK

Comment: FF4 is OK for me

Comment: I can repro on FF4/Windows XP but the funny part is if I change the zoom level up or down a level or two, it actually stops it.  Only at the default zoom does it do it.

Comment: Yeah, with zoom of more than 100% it's not cropped..

Comment: Repro in Win7/FF 3.6.17. Looking at the layout, I think I'd rather see less whitespace between the tag, the x and the number of questions (as opposed to widening the whole column).

Answer (score 2):

This has been likely fixed a long time ago: the tag counts now wrap.

Comment: No [meta-tag:status-completed] then :-)?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I forgot to press save...