# Long tags partially hide question counts in edit mode previewing

Tags: bug, tags, design, edits

It seems long tags can hide question counts when previewing them in edit mode:

[image]

In the example above, it apparently shows that only one question used the tag. The [tag webpage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling-and-floor-functions?sort=newest) shows the actual number of 1.8k questions (so the .8k is missing in the preview).

Can this be fixed?

Related: [Long tag names cause the total question count to be truncated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93332/long-tag-names-cause-the-total-question-count-to-be-truncated) which is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but in an older version.

Comment: It can even be worse than this: go to [literature.se] and type "jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell" into the tag box - near the end, not only is the question count hidden, but the "?" help button is as well.

Comment: I just noticed today that this seems to get worse when the window is thinner (and then persist when the window is resized bigger); even shorter tags get cut off badly. Not sure if that's a recent development or not

Comment: For some reason there's even a [dot when question count is 126.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bPly.jpg)